# IPtables : Limit number of new ssh connections per minute

Tags: iptables, firewall

I need to ensure on my server that maximum  new ssh connections per minute are not more then 5.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT
```

Above IPtables rule work for me, but it will not allow new connections after one minute.

Any pointers how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add --reject-with tcp-reset so that the rejected connections get closed gracefully otherwise you're going to have a bunch of SYN_WAITs sitting around.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```